# silverlight xml serialization

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Is there a way to resolve the below build error when doing xml serialization? I get the same error for System.Xml.XmlSerialization assembly.

> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization,
>   Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" and
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing
>   "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e" arbitrarily.

Comment: You have 2 versions of a DLL  'available'. A misconfiguration in your project or on the target PC.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using two or more versions of an assembly in the same application. To resolve this issue you need to make use of "Alias".

[Check out this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx)  to know abt alias.

Or,  You can redirect an assembly binding reference to another version of an assembly by using entries in the application or machine configuration files using the `<bindingRedirect>`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2.aspx

Comment: Please don't post links that are specific to a .NET Framework version unless your answer is specific to that version.